# Writing a Teleoperation Node for a Linux-Supported Joystick

Tags: joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I am starting learning ROS. I want to do the tutorial "Writing a Teleoperation Node for a Linux-Supported Joystick" in http://www.ros.org/wiki/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode but when i try to run the command "roslaunch learning_joy turtle_joy.launch" I get

ERROR: cannot launch node of type [learning_joy/turtle_teleop_joy]: can't locate node [turtle_teleop_joy] in package [learning_joy]

I appreciate your help a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43116/writing-a-teleoperation-node-for-a-linux-supported-joystick/) by [jcparrad](https://answers.ros.org/users/3148/jcparrad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mahathi92](https://answers.ros.org/users/61049/mahathi92/) on 2020-10-16**:
I am getting the exact same error.

But, if you go to ~/catkin_ws/ and

> > catkin_make

you get the build files in ~/catkin_ws/build/learning_joy

**Run the executable using:**

> > ./turtle_teleop_joy

**Make sure you do**

> > rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node

> > rosrun joy joy_node

Also initialize the l_scale_ and a_scale_ variables to some integer (I made them 10).

I still get the same error when I try using the launch file. Please help if anyone got to know why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial doesn't explicitly tell you to compile your code, but you should make sure to run the command

```
rosmake learning_joy
```

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3